# Please suggest a way to solve this complicated system of ODEs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of ODEs. Can anybody please suggest how can I solve this system? I have tried Maple but it not giving any output, it just gets hang.
\begin{align}
        -(c+\alpha)f^{\prime}+(a_{1}-a_{2}c)g^{\prime\prime}+(bg+\sigma f^{\prime})(f^{2}+g^{2})-2(\lambda+\mu)f(ff^{\prime}+gg^{\prime})-\lambda f^{\prime}(f^{2}+g^{2})=\,0,\\
        (c+\alpha)g^{\prime}+(a_{1}-a_{2}c)f^{\prime\prime}+(bf-\sigma g^{\prime})(f^{2}+g^{2})+2g(\lambda+\mu)(ff^{\prime}+gg^{\prime})+\lambda g^{\prime}(f^{2}+g^{2})=\,0
    \end{align}

Here $'=\frac{d}{dt}$, where $c, \alpha, b, \lambda, \mu$ are all constants.

Comment: A symbolic solution seems unlikely, so are you looking for a numerical solution?

Comment: No, I need analytic solution only.

Comment: @LutzL: Please suggest any working method if there is any.

Comment: As I said, it is almost surely impossible. You can try to transform into polar coordinates as you have $r^2$ and $r'r$ terms, but I would expect that you get farther only for special selections of the constants.